# How do you get changes from a remote repo when git displays "Repository is up to date."?

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

I'm not sure what is caused this, but my local repo is missing changes from master/origin and I can't seem to get them.

- When I try a `pull`, git returns "Repository is already up to date. No changes to pull."
- I attempted to `merge` master/origin into my local repo, but it doesn't bring down the changes.
- I pulled down master/origin to my local master repo and attempted to merge local master to local branch.
- I merge master/origin to [my branch]/origin, and then merge.

The fact is that orgin/master has stuff that is different than my local repo has.  How do I tell git to "grab changes from master and bring them down to my local branch"?

This seems like it should be a simple process, so not sure what the cause is.

[image]

Comment: A `git pull` should pull & merge. It sounds like your remotes are misconfigured, and you're not pulling what you think you're pulling. Unfortunately, there's not enough info here to sort it out. You'll need to check which local branches are associated with which remote branches - start with `git remote -v` to see your remote URLs and `git branch -vv` to see the relationships between branches.

Comment: Can I just tell git to compare the two branches in some way?  Feels like merge should do this, but it doesn't work.

Comment: It **will** do it - I suspect it is not doing it in your case because your repository is not configured the way you think it is.

Comment: I just attached a history timeline.  The gray line is local master.  I merged local master into my branch, hoping that changes from master would move to the branch.

Comment: I just checked the local file system and the needed files from the merge are actually there. It turned out that Visual Studio is just not showing them for some reason. Any idea why it would be doing this?

Answer (score 2):

You ask if there's not just some way to "just tell git to compare the two branches in some way" - that's what it's doing, and it's not finding any differences. That's the root cause of your problem - it's not finding differences that you believe are there. You'll need to find out why those differences are not where you expect them to be.

The way I see it, there are two possibilities:

**The simple one**: the changes you are looking for haven't been pushed to `origin`. Check with your co-workers.

**The more complicated one**: your local repository is not configured correctly to pull from `origin` - either `origin` is not what it should be or your `master` branch is not pulling from the correct remote branch. To diagnose this kind of problem, do the following (1):

1. open a terminal in your editor (Ctrl+Backtick in VS Code)
2. type the following: `git remote -v`
3. you'll see something like this:

```
origin git@github.com:user/my-repository.git (fetch)
origin git@github.com:user/my-repository.git (push)
```

This tells you which remote server and repository you will be connecting to when you pull (fetch) or push.

4. type the following: `git branch -vv`
5. you'll see something like this:

```
develop      abcde1234 [origin/develop] last commit message on develop
master       1234abcde [origin/master] last commit message on master
```

This lists all the local branches (ie. `develop`, `master`) and which remote branches they are "connected" to (ie. local `develop` -> origin `develop`).

If my suspicion is correct, then you'll find one or both of the following to be true:

1. origin is not pointing to the repository you expect, or
2. your `master` branch is not connected to the correct origin branch.

If either of these is the case, then you're not going to get the commits that you believe to be on `origin/master` merged into your local branch.

If *neither* of these is the case, then that means that the commits you believe are on origin are not there - perhaps someone didn't push them?

---

(1) I'm doing this in Visual Studio Code on a Linux machine. The steps may be different on Windows or in the full Visual Studio product.

Comment: I just checked the local file system and the needed files from the merge are actually there.  It turned out that Visual Studio is just not showing them for some reason.  Any idea why it would be doing this?